# Editing the Summary View in List Viewer

Tags: list-view, custom-list, list-view-web-part

It appears that only certain columns can be displayed in the Summary View for list viewers. I am wondering if there is a way to get around this. I have one additional column from the list I'd like to display in the same format as summary view. I have edited the summary view to include my column but it doesn't show in the viewer.
How can I accomplish this in MOSS 2007?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you edited the summary view on the list itself, after you created the list view, you need to go back into the listview web part, re-select the summary view, and then apply it.  Views on lists and listview webparts are not synced, they can be changed and edited nonindependent of each other.  The column you added, should display under the body column (if announcement list).

If you don't like the placement of the column, you will need to break out SharePoint designer.